# How to access JSON object's values with Polymer's <iron-ajax>?

Tags: json, ajax, polymer

I was able to do this with jQuery but stuck on Polymer. How can I retrieve and list out the values, e.g. "title" and "productID"? This doesn't seem asd sn't seem asd sn't seem asd sn't seem asd

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
 </head>

 <body>
    <template is="dom-bind">
     <iron-ajax url="bookeo.json" last-response="{{item}}" auto></iron-ajax>
      <iron-list items="[[item.data]]" style="height:40em" as="customer">
        <template>
          <div class="item">
            <b>[[customer.title]] - [[customer.productId]]</b>
          </div>
        </template>
      </iron-list>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first part of the JSON file

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "John Smith",
      "participants": {
        "numbers": [
          {
            "peopleCategoryId": "adults",
            "number": 4
          }
        ]

      },
      "productId": "2129Y4KNB2DC9F",
      "price": 
        "totalPaid": {
          "amount": "0",
          "currency": "USD"
        }
    },
(followed by more objects...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually pretty close. A few problems I found:

1. You've misplaced `as="customer"` on [`iron-ajax`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) (which does not have an `as` property) when it should actually be on [`iron-list`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#property-as).
2. You're referencing `productID` when the data actually contains `productId` (note the last lowercase `d`).
3. Your JSON is malformed, as `price` is missing a value.

This is what your code should look like:

```html
<template is="dom-bind">
  <iron-ajax url="bookeo.json" last-response="{{item}}" auto></iron-ajax>
  <iron-list items="[[item.data]]" style="height:40em" as="customer">
    <template>
      <div class="item">
        <b>[[customer.title]] - [[customer.productID]]</b>
      </div>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
</template>
```

And your JSON should be something like this:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "John Smith",
      "participants": {
        "numbers": [
          {
            "peopleCategoryId": "adults",
            "number": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      "productId": "2129Y4KNB2DC9F",

      "price": "1.23", /* NOTE: price data was originally missing */

      "totalPaid": {
        "amount": "0",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    },
  ...
  ]
}
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l2mOpn9y7OOaP9d7cGTx?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Tony19 I accepted your response, it was working in plunkr (before polygit went down) so I copied your code into my project (even the bookeo.json file you used) but still can't get the data to display on my end. I'm sure all 5 files are linked correctly (as well as the json file), not sure what's going on. I modified my initial code to reflect your edits.

Comment: @Jake Can you provide a demo of your problem code? (perhaps a sample project in GitHub)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <iron-ajax url="bookeo.json" last-response="{{item}}" auto as="customer"></iron-ajax>
    <iron-list items="[[item.data]]" style="height:40em">
      <template>
        <div class="item">
        <b>[[item.title]] - [[item.productID]]</b>
        </div>
      </template>
    </iron-list>
</template>
```